# Laravel Blade @extends and @yield not working

Tags: laravel

So I have input.blade.php which extends the register.blade.php(which extends app.blade.php) but the content in @section('input.agent')of my input.blade.php is not visible in my register.blade.php with @yield('input.agent') which is under the card body tab pane (a little hard to find but it's there).

This is my register.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-agent-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-agent" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-agent" aria-selected="true">Agent</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-development_officer-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-development_officer" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-development_officer" aria-selected="false">Development Officer</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-agent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-agent-tab">@yield('input.agent')</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-development_officer" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-development_officer-tab">Hello</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is my input.blade.php

```
@extends('auth.register')

@section('input.agent')
    <h1>Hello</h1>
@endsection
```

this is the web.php under routes

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

My directories:

```
view=>auth=>register.blade.php

view=>input=>input.blade.php

view=>layouts=>app.blade.php
```

Kindly help me
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: where is  `@yield('input.agent')`?

Comment: <div class="card-body">
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-agent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-agent-tab">**@yield('input.agent')**</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-development_officer" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-development_officer-tab">Hello</div>
            </div>
        </div

Comment: Yes but WHERE did you put that "yield"?

Comment: Sorry. I can see it now. All looks fine. Can you see the card body in the browser? If you write some text beside the @yield you can see it?

Comment: Yeah I can see if say I typed Hello world

Comment: How are you  loading this view? Please can you show your route/controller method?

Answer (score 0):

try using `@include` instead of `@yield`:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-agent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-agent-tab">@include('input.input')</div>
```

in your `register` view.

and remove:

```
@extends('auth.register')

@section('input.agent')
@endsection
```

in your `input` view (leave just the html).

otherwise you would have to return the `input` view instead of `register`.

Comment: It worked, thanks, but what if I have two input sections for two types of users and want them in one input.blade.php?

Comment: then leave everything as it was and create a new route like `Route::get('/input-register', function () { return view('input.input'); });`

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand, could you explain a bit in detail about the Route: method

Comment: Yep, I'll try. The register routes are inside the `Auth::routes();`. They are created by Laravel . So, when you go to `your-domain/register` in your browser, the returned view will be `register.blade.php`, which extends from `layouts.app`, that's why you can use the `layouts.app` `@yield('content')` like you are doing. To do the same with the `@yield('input.input')` you must return other view wich extends from the `register` view. And then you can use `@section` to fill the `@yield` in the parent view. Sorry if I do not explain myself well, english is not my native language.

Comment: Sorry, is `'input.agent'` not `'input.input'`

Comment: how can I access the Auth::routes(); to add an entry to it then? BTW thanks a lot for helping me out. Cheers!

Comment: You can remove Auth::routes(), from web.php, and implement your own routes, according to the controllers. The Auth::routes() are in vendor folder, technically it's not recommended to edit files in vendor folder

Comment: I think is better create a custom regirter route to do what you wan t

Comment: Alright, I might have to watch a few videos to know about Routes as I am new to the whole Laravel approach. Thanks though for helping me out mate. :)

Comment: try adding this route `Route::get('/my-custom-register', function () { return view('input.input'); });` and type in your browser `your-domain/my-custom-register` and see what happen. good luck!

Comment: Thanks a million this was exactly what I needed, it solved my problem, but now I want to implement it in my default domain/register page. How can I do that?

Comment: I' m on my phone now. I' m sure there is an allready aswered questiion on stackoverflow to do that, or you can ask "how to overwrite the register route" or something like that. Also you can google a tutorial